# How does Ahsoka know about Anakin wanting to leave the order?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the **season 5** of *The Clone Wars* season finale "The Wrong Jedi",

> Ahsoka Tano makes the decision to walk away from the Jedi order after the decision was made to let her back in following her "great Jedi trial" of being falsely accused of bombing the Jedi Temple. The Jedi Council cast her out in order to allow the Republic to try her in their courts.  We know the Jedi Council feels the weight of this decision by Ahsoka to walk away but only Anakin, her master, runs to catch her and attempt one last minute plea to reconsider.

When Anakin finally catches up to her outside the Temple courtyard, he tries to reason with her and says

> ANAKIN: I understand.  More than you realize, I understand wanting to walk away from the Order.

The last words spoken by her are rather jarring...

> AHSOKA: I know.

My question is, what does she know about her master?  Does she know nothing specific and just has a Jedi feeling and intuition about her master?  We can as viewers recall in the movies two major violations that Anakin is guilty of; Slaughtering the Sand People that killed his mother, and his forbidden marriage to Padme.  We've also have seen a few instances in The Clone Wars, where Anakin has been a bit un-Jedi-like in front of Ahsoka (though exact episodes and scene escape me, since there were like 120 of them...) such as bouts of anger, etc.  Considering the situation, Anakin's reaction, and given, this is the last words of the 5th season, should we assume she knows these things of her master?

Considering what is currently happening on Rebels, these last couple of episodes from Season 5 seem so important moving forward toward the Rebel's season 2 finale coming up where we know that

> they will meet in combat.

Comment: Oh come on. Spoilers!

Comment: That Ashoka leaves.

Comment: Partially my fault though

Comment: @Iceman So? I wouldn't spoil Twilight Zone twists, and they're decades old.

Comment: I will change it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think with the connection Anakin, and Ahsoka had, she most likely noticed something; Anakin was very connected to people, and had a a lot of emotional attachments, which iirc, is against the Jedi code. That's really what I can see making her know that Anakin wanted to walk away from the order.