# What does the guard take away from Ahsoka in episode "The Wrong Jedi" from the Clone Wars series?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, ahsoka-tano

At the end of the trial, we see a guard ripping something away from Ahsoka, some kind of jewelry.

What is the jewelry and what's the significance of the guards' act?

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121288/how-does-ahsoka-know-about-anakin-wanting-to-leave-the-order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Silka beads](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Silka_bead). It's what Padawan learners that don't have hair wear in lieu of a [padawan braid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Padawan_braid). Removing it would of course symbolise her expulsion from the Order, stripping her of her rank of Padawan. It's also what Anakin holds out to her when they ask her back, she instead closes his hand around them and refuses.

Comment: From *The Jedi Path - A Manual for Students of the Force* - https://66.media.tumblr.com/baebf091b08fa58cf2a251e5976b20b0/tumblr_inline_p6bwdaNFF31r4eyz7_540.png